# I want to link MS Access to an Entity Framework 5 code-first data table

Tags: ms-access, entity-framework-5

The issue is that Entity Framework 5 uses a naming convention that inserts a period ("."), an illegal character in MS Access. Example: "PK_dbo.[ColumnName]"

It appears that Entity Framework no longer provides a way to change naming conventions. I could write a script that changes all of my PK names, but I feel like this is a common enough issue that perhaps there's some other method or workaround that I just don't know about.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an Entity Framework provider for a different DBMS (i.e. for SQL Server).
Microsoft does not provide EF Provider for Microsoft Access.
You can find a provider here
http://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/

There is not a compiled version and it works only with EF 6.1.3.